# ListView control throwing an exception on ItemInserted event

Tags: asp.net, listview, events, exception, insert

I am getting an exception with ListView control Item Inserted event. I have the field city value being populated by a databinded dropdownlist control.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> **Insert is disabled for this control. 
>    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. >Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>   Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Insert is disabled for this control.**
>
> Source Error: 
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information >regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack >trace below.
>
> Stack Trace: 
>   [InvalidOperationException: Insert is disabled for this control.]
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteInsert(IDictionary values) +88405
>     System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Insert(IDictionary values, DataSourceViewOperationCallback >callback) +81
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.HandleInsert(ListViewItem item, Boolean causesValidation) >+716
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String >validationGroup) +1333
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +315
>     System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItem.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +141
>     System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +114
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +159
>     System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String >eventArgument) +10
>     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) >+13
>     System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>     System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean >includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

The markup is follows

```
<asp:ListView ID="LstVwCompanyDetails" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntDatSrcCompanyDetails" 
   ClientIDMode="Static" DataKeyNames="YPCode" InsertItemPosition="LastItem" 
    OnItemInserting="LstVwCompanyDetails_ItemInserting"
 >
..............
..............
<InsertItemTemplate>
  <table style="box-shadow: 5px 2px 10px black;background-color: darkolivegreen; color: ghostwhite;">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <asp:TextBox ID="County" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("County") %>'  />
     </td>
    <td>
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCityList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="EntDataSrcSelectedCities"  DataTextField="city" DataValueField="cityID"  ClientIDMode="Static">
       </asp:DropDownList>         
       </td>
       <td>
         <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" ToolTip="Add details" Text="Add" />
         <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />


The code in ItemInserting event handler is
==================
   protected void LstVwCompanyDetails_ItemInserting(object sender, ListViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlCity = (DropDownList)LstVwCompanyDetails.InsertItem.FindControl("ddlCityList"); 
            //e.Item.FindControl("ddlCityList") as DropDownList;
            if (ddlCity != null)
            {
                e.Values["CompanyCode"] = (Convert.ToInt32(ddlCity.SelectedValue));
            }
        }
```

===============

Thank you
Nate

Comment: Have a look on this - [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002927/insert-update-delete-is-disabled-for-this-control-message-of-entitydatasource)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, There is primary key and it has been specified.